# Windows WSL2 and git

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2, everything seems ok except that the files in Windows are not synced within WSL, what I mean by that is, if I navigate to a git repo (folder) and run `git status`, I see two different results inside WSL console and Windows Powershell, the WSL result is incorrect.

result from Powershell

`nothing to commit, working tree clean`

result from WSL

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  modified:   .gitattributes
  modified:   .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
  modified:   .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug.md
  modified:   .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/feature.md
  modified:   .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/question.md
  modified:   .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/regression.md
  modified:   .github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
  modified:   .gitignore
  modified:   .travis.yml
  modified:   Analytics.md
  modified:   CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
  modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md
  modified:   LICENSE.md
  modified:   MAINTAINERS
  modified:   README.md
  modified:   SECURITY.md

There are a lot of changes to commit I just copied the first few lines
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: How did you get them into WSL?

Comment: @fredrik, the WSL mounts the Windows file system so `c:/folder1` becomes `/mnt/c/folder1` inside WSL

Comment: Then it should update automatically, if it does not - we need more information.

Comment: Or even better, contact Microsoft support

Comment: please at least post the two git status calls and their output, because from here I can't understand what _incorrect_ means

Comment: could you post the full path to both resources where you run git status?

Comment: @DaemonPainter `c:\users\bahram\Documents\github\atsz\kubernetes` and `/mnt/c/users/bahram/Documents/github/atsz/kubernetes`

Comment: ok now I am intrigued. Looks like the two systems are somehow out of sync, which I thought would be not possible. Can you shut down the WLS and restart it? Maybe you already tried.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the same branch in both environments?

Comment: @DaemonPainter I ran `wsl --shutdown`, did not help

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes, both on the same branch

Comment: are there third-party softwares involved, like github desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with WSL1, but it's gone with WSL2 actually. The issue reproduced in case I used *git clone* inside Linux machine but then opened this folder from Windows host. IDEA hasn't recognised that the folder has any git initiated repo. I guess it was something with permissions to *.git* folder over the sharing stack (not sure is it *samba* or something else). After I switched my distribution to WSL2 everything became fine.